# General solution to $f^{(n)}=f$ but $f^{(k)}\ne f$ for $k<n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We know that

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

and

$$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}\sin(x)=\sin(x)$$

What is the general solution $f$ to

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)&=f(x) \\
\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)&\ne f(x)\quad \mathrm{for}\>\>k<n \quad?
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solutions are linear combinations of complex exponentials:
$$f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{\omega^k x}$$
where $\omega$ is a primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity. In this way, we have
$$\frac{d^nf}{dx}\!(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\omega^{kn} e^{\omega^k x} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{\omega^k x}=f(x)$$

(I'm not sure how to prove this is totally general, but my guess it is follows pretty easily by linear algebraic considerations; in particular we have $n$ degrees of freedom which is what we would expect from an $n^\text{th}$ order ODE.)

If the set $\{n\}\cup \{k: a_k\neq 0\}$ is mutually coprime, then no smaller derivative is equal to $f$; this is a pretty straightforward exercise.

The trigonometric functions come into this picture when we demand real solutions: since $i$ is a primitive fourth root of unity we can write
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2i}e^{ix}-\frac{1}{2i}e^{-ix}=\sin(x)$$
and similarly for cosine.

Comment: Why the set you described is a total solution: 1)  $e^{\omega^kx}$ are linearly independent if $\omega^k$ are mutually distinct; 2) each such function is solution of the differential equation; 3) recall a linear differential equation with constant coefficients of $n$-th order has the space of solutions of dimension $n$ (easy proof by passing to a system of linear equations of first order).

Comment: Thanks! (3) is the part I didn't remember how to do, but passing to a system makes sense.